# Is it possible to rename bundle selections in the front-end only?

Tags: magento-1.8, frontend, bundled-product

I've created a bundle product with the intention of allowing a customer to select their medium from a drop-down menu: Either MP3 or a physical CD. Each is their own distinct product which are enabled but not visible. I had to edit some configs to allow downloadable products to be part of a bundle but it appears to be working fine. Currently however, it shows the product names in the drop-down menu. Is there a way to have these be overridden (in the front-end only) to, for example, "MP3" and "Compact Disk".

I could just make many products all with the name "MP3", but that would make the customer's download page look very confusing. I could also call the products "(product name) MP3" but I feel like it's not going to be the most elegant solution.

Is it possible to achieve my goal in this way (or in any way?).

Comment: do you want to link the page or paste some sample code in?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible, but it will likely require developer customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending if only in the selectbox or on other parts like Cart/Checkout/checkout-mail it could be really easy.

1. add a new attribute for the products you want to "rename", call it for example bundled_name
2. search for the correct template where the selectbox is generated, and add an if(){} part, where you return this custom attribute, if set.

Depending on what you need, I can extend this answer later, when I have more time.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'd love it if you could extend this answer, it looks like a very elegant solution to the problem. I'm not certain on the "proper" way to find the attribute. I know there's $_product->_data... although I think that's the wrong way to go about it.